# Java: Making Prog1Tools portable

Tags: java, package, portability

I made an USB Device for programming Java portable.
I'm using Notepad++ with plugins by following [this instructions](http://www.quarkphysics.ca/scripsi/java_notepad/)
Since I'm learning Java with a book and it's using the Prog1Tools package for I/O, I would like to ask, is there any way to make this package portable?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What are the Prog1Tools?

Comment: It's a package but only got a german documentation (resp. I only found one in german) idk if it helps you, here:
 [link](http://www.mps.de/grundkurs_java_2011/software/Prog1Tools/IOTools.html)

Comment: If you use the package as an folder or jar you can just copy them on your usb drive. For compilation and execution you have to set the right classpath (e.g. using the `-cp` switch with your java(c) call).

Comment: so I have to modify the scripts, adding _"\Programme\packages\Prog1Tools.zip"_ to _cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" 
"\Programme\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javac" $(FILE_NAME)_ ?

Comment: don't know the content of Prog1Tools.zip (it could contain a jar or class files) but you may have to extract it first and add it to the classpath (according to Part3 2b in the linked instructions). The instructions just cover using the jdk without any lib. Pro tip: Read about the parameter classpath.